# Sharing files / folders between user accounts

Tags: finder, permission, sharing, file, file-sharing

I'm trying to share folders between 2 different user accounts and not having any luck, I keep getting the red 'locked' icon on my folders.

So I have 2 folders in **User A** and would like to transfer to **User B**

I tried copying the folders into the Public folders of both user accounts, and set the permissions to read & write for everyone.

I then clicked the cog icon and applied to enclosing files / folders.

I then login to User B and the folder is still locked and cannot view what is inside. This is the same regardless of whose Public folder I look in.

[image]

Comment: Just use `/Users/Shared/`.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks, that works nicely